# Retaining values even after form submit in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, retain

I am trying to create a simple calculator application .

`calculator.html.erb`

```
<input type=text name="operand_one" value="0"></td>
<input type=text name="operand_two" value="0"></td>
.
.
.
<input type=text name="output" value="<% =@result %>"></td>
```

I am able to get the output correctly but the values of the first two text boxes changes to 0 , I need to know how to retain these values ..

Comment: Well, you are specifically telling them to have a value of "0", so that's what they have. What have you tried, that didn't work? What values should they have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're hardcoding the value to "0" with this part of the code

```
value="0"
```

you could change the lines to

```
<input type=text name="operand_one" value="@value_one"></td> #etc...
```

and in your controller

```
@value_one = 0 unless X
```

but `X` depends on how your controller works - do you go to a new action to solve the problem in the calculator?  if so you'll have to use the params hash.

Not related to the question, but why are you using text for your calculation fields?  and are you hard coding that html or it's just the output?

Comment: Thanks a lot , it worked exactly the way I want .

Comment: sure . Is there a way to do the same for select box as well ?

Comment: [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease) should help.  it really depends what your view looks like